# How to create and display custom category attributes

Tags: category-attribute, custom-attributes

As the title says, i want to be able to create and display custom category attributes.

I tried this extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manage-category-customer-and-customer-address-attributes.html

And this extension allows me to create the attributes, but I dont know how to display them in my template files. I tried the following code:

```
<?php echo Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')->getAttributeRawValue($_category->getId(), "subtitel", Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()); ?>
```

but that did not do the trick.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In which file are you trying to echo the new attribute (looks like a .phtml). Some times you need to load the category again to load all the attributes, you can't just rely that the new attribute will be already loaded in the object. So first you could use xdebug to check wich attributes are loaded, or if you are not using xdebug I guess you could do var_dump() or print_r(). If the attribute is not there then load the category like this:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
```

Then you can check again for your new attribute like this:

```
$category->getSubtitel(); 
//or like this
$category->getData('subtitel');
```

Final advice, just make sure you get only the attributes you need, so you could just load the set of attributes you need each time.

Comment: I am abit new to magento development, so i am not sure how to use xdebug, haven't heard of it before. To answer your quesiton i am trying to output a special titel, specific for each category. So i am trying to output the value from category/view.phtml

Comment: I tried loading the model like you said, and my attribute data is still not being displayed

Comment: That is fine, then just place a print_r($_category->getData()) in your .phtml file and you will see all the attributes. There is also another alternative you could use Mage::log() and then instead of printing the output of $_category->getData() you can put that into a log file, if you want to do this then place this in your .phtml Mage::log(print_r($_category->getData()), true), 1, 'nameforyour.log'); Dont worry if the file doesn't exist Magento will create it for you, the file will be located in MAGENTO_ROOT_PATH/var/log/.

Comment: Not sure what's going on. But you can check that your attribute was created like this: select e.* from eav_attribute e join eav_entity_type t on e.entity_type_id = t.entity_type_id
where t.entity_type_code = 'catalog_category' and e.attribute_code  = 'subtitel'; Take note of the attribute_id and backend_type and then you can check if a given category has the attribute set and what value has like this: 
select * from catalog_category_entity_varchar where attribute_id = ATTRIBUTE_ID_HERE and entity_id = CATEGORY_ID_HERE;

Comment: Forgot to mention, I just assumed that your attribute was a varchar attribute. So with the first query you will see which type of attribute you created if you don't know already. So if it's indeed a varchar then the second query should work, if it's something else then you need to change the table name: catalog_category_entity_decimal, catalog_category_entity_int, catalog_category_entity_text, catalog_category_entity_datetime

Comment: It is a varchar. And when i go to my test category, i can see the attribute and the data i put in. So it is definetly being stored. All i need to know is how to display the data in frontend. And when i var_dump getData('subtitel'), after loading the model it returns NULL

Comment: BTW: this sql query: "select e.* from eav_attribute e join eav_entity_type t on e.entity_type_id = t.entity_type_id where t.entity_type_code = 'catalog_category' and e.attribute_code = 'subtitel';" returns empty

Comment: That is weird. Are you using flat tables? If so check like this: select * from catalog_category_flat_store_1 where entity_id = CATEGORY_ID_HERE; (replace the _1 by the store_id you want to check). Also could you show me how you are loading the category and how you are doing the output?

Comment: I am not sure waht to put as the category id or the store id. I must say i am getting a bit confused. I am use to creating new product attributes and displaying them on the product page. All i wanted was to do the same for a category page. But that is not native, so i installed the HWG module, and that creates the attribute. But i simply dont have a working snippet to put it into my template files.